# Stardog: Unable to load class [org.postgresql.Driver]

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, stardog, knowledge-graph

I'm trying to follow the Stardog tutorial for [using virtual graphs](https://www.stardog.com/tutorials/using-virtual-graphs/).

As per the instructions, I set up the `$STARDOG_EXT` environment variable.

> **JDBC Setup**
>
> Stardog does not ship with JDBC drivers so you need to
>   manually copy the JAR file containing the driver for your RDBMS into
>   the classpath of the Stardog server. The preferred way of doing this
>   is by setting the `STARDOG_EXT` environment variable to point to a
>   directory outside the Stardog installation directory and copy the jar
>   file there:
>
> ```
> $ export STARDOG_EXT=/opt/stardog/ext
> $ mkdir $STARDOG_EXT
> $ cp JDBC_JAR_FILE $STARDOG_EXT
> ```

I have the JAR file copied in the above-mentioned location as indicated below.

```
bilesh@vm-ubuntu:~$ echo $STARDOG_EXT 
/opt/stardog/ext

bilesh@vm-ubuntu:~$ cd $STARDOG_EXT

bilesh@vm-ubuntu:/opt/stardog/ext$ ls -la
total 916
drwxr-xr-x 2 root    root      4096 Feb 19 20:22 .
drwxr-xr-x 9 stardog stardog   4096 Feb 19 20:21 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 stardog root    927447 Feb 19 20:22 postgresql-42.2.10.jar
```

But I'm getting the error `Unable to load class: org.postgresql.Driver` when trying to create a virtual graph using PostgreSQL.

```
bilesh@vm-ubuntu:~$ sudo /opt/stardog/stardog-server.sh start
Starting stardog
Starting Stardog server in background, see /var/opt/stardog//stardog.log for more information.

bilesh@vm-ubuntu:~$ cd Workspace/Stardog/pgsql_demo

bilesh@vm-ubuntu:~/Workspace/Stardog/pgsql_demo$ stardog-admin virtual add music.properties music_mappings.ttl
Unable to load class: org.postgresql.Driver from ClassLoader:sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@619a5dff;ClassLoader:java.net.URLClassLoader@3b63d1de
```

My PostgreSQL properties file (`music.properties`) and the mapping file (`music_mappings.ttl`) are in the location - `~/Workspace/Stardog/pgsql_demo`.

Comment: do you get the same problem if you do not use sudo to start the server?

Comment: @BryanA - Have to run it with `sudo`. The script needs to write in some places the user doesn't have write access.

Answer (score 0):

To make it work, I placed the JAR file (`postgresql-42.2.10.jar`) in `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/ext/` and restarted the server.

After that, I was able to successfully create the virtual graph.

Not sure if this is how I have to do this going forward.

Comment: which version of Stardog are you running?  i have had trouble running using sudo because of permissions when it runs as root.  you could try creating a system service that runs it under the stardog user account you have there - but i dont know if thats the problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `STARDOG_EXT` differently when using the package. It won't be visible to the daemon environment if you set it only in your shell. See the docs here: https://docs.stardog.com/get-started/install-stardog/linux-installation#package-layout

Also you should use systemd/systemctl to start the server when installed this way